# Error in Decompression?

Tags: c#, html, web, gzip

I am writing a crawler for a website.
Its response is gzip encoded.

I am not able to parse correctly a particular field, though the decompression is successful.
I am also using htmlagilitypack to parse it,

the parsed value of the field is only a part of the original value 
as an example :
I am getting only /wEWAwKc04vTCQKb86mzBwKln/PuCg==
whereas the firebug shows the actual value as much longer:
 /wEWBgKj7IuJCgKb86mzBwKln/PuCgLT250qAtC0+8cMAvimiNYD

what does the '==' at the end means?
I am assuming it that its a error on decompressors behalf?

Comment: Can you show us any code? _How_ are you inflating the compressed data? Are you converting any returned result from bytes to a string? If so, which encoding? et cetera.

Comment: == is used commonly to terminate BAS64-encoded strings.

Comment: this is a hidden field in a webpage that I am trying to read.,
page returned is in gzip compressed, and this is a direct field, that is used again while postback. So semantically it could be just a constant variable to track the session.

Answer (score 0):

The character `=` is added by the [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Encoding the following sentence

> Man is distinguished, not only by his reason, but by this singular passion from other animals, which is a lust of the mind, that by a perseverance of delight in the continued and indefatigable generation of knowledge, exceeds the short vehemence of any carnal pleasure.

you would get

> TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCBieSB0aGlz
>     IHNpbmd1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbSBvdGhlciBhbmltYWxzLCB3aGljaCBpcyBhIGx1c3Qgb2Yg
>     dGhlIG1pbmQsIHRoYXQgYnkgYSBwZXJzZXZlcmFuY2Ugb2YgZGVsaWdodCBpbiB0aGUgY29udGlu
>     dWVkIGFuZCBpbmRlZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXRpb24gb2Yga25vd2xlZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRo
>     ZSBzaG9ydCB2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4=

The `=` character can only be present at the end of the Base64 string. If you obtain it, it means you are probably getting all the characters; vice versa is not true, as that character is used as padding character, and it is not always mandatory in all the Base64 implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a problem with decompression. The page has obviously been correctly decompressed. Otherwise your software would likely throw an error or you'd see just a bunch of strange characters.

However, what you get is an ASCII string that's obviously in Base 64 encoding. The equal signs at the end appear if the original binary data is not a multiple of 3 bytes. So that's all perfect Base 64 data.

As to why your crawler gets different data than Firefox with Firebug: I don't know but can image many reasons. These are two separate browsing sessions and the web site might just assign them different session IDs or somehow record some history of the session.

Anyhow, at the end of the day I don't understand your problem. What exactly are you unable to parse? Do you get some kind of error? What do you mean by *field*? Are you talking about a field of an HTML form?